How to inject/insert/install popper js in Blazor app
I am developing my first Blazor application. I used a Bootstrap 5 DropDown Button.
<div class="dropdown">
    <button type="button" title="Print" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown">
        <i class="bi bi-printer"></i>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><button type="submit" id="print-1" class="btn btn-link border-0" @onclick="() => Print(AppliedReporting.ReportType.Preview)">Preview</button></li>
        <li><button type="submit" id="print-2" class="btn btn-link border-0" @onclick="() => Print(AppliedReporting.ReportType.PDF)">PDF</button></li>
        <li><button type="submit" id="print-3" class="btn btn-link border-0" @onclick="() => Print(AppliedReporting.ReportType.Excel)">Excel</button></li>
        <li><button type="submit" id="print-4" class="btn btn-link border-0" @onclick="() => Print(AppliedReporting.ReportType.Word)">Word</button></li>
        <li><button type="submit" id="print-5" class="btn btn-link border-0" @onclick="() => Print(AppliedReporting.ReportType.HTML)">HTML</button></li>
    </ul>
</div>

But the list of dropdown is not dropping as should be.
After a long study. I realised that popper should be installed in the Blazor application.
I have failed to install it after several attempts. like;
Copy a popper.js file from web to the location of the blazor app folder.
Add https://github.com/KristofferStrube/Blazor.Popper framework and
add
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous"\>

But unfortunately I am failing to active the dropdown list.
what is the best and easiest way to solve this problem?
I am trying to install / inject / insert popper js in Blazor App in VS 2022 Community.

Did the follow the Usage instructions from the GitHub repository you linked to? Based on your question it feels like you've missed 2 or 3 key steps in the implementation.

I have tested the code. You will not need install anything. Just add the script reference in the App.razor like following the dropdown will work.
...
<body>
    <Routes @rendermode="InteractiveServer" />
    <script src="_framework/blazor.web.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
...



Thanks.

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-cuYeSxntonz0PPNlHhBs68uyIAVpIIOZZ5JqeqvYYIcEL727kskC66kF92t6Xl2V" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

I also fixed this by Add extra @  "@@popperjs" becuase single @ use for c# codes. and double @@ for insert @ this sign in blazor page.
